# Why is SVG stroke-width : 1 making lines transparent?

Tags: svg, width, transparent, stroke

I'm creating stock charts with svg and I'm having a problem when I set the stroke-width of my path elements to 1.  Instead of making the lines more narrow, it just makes it the same size as stroke-width:2 but slightly transparent.  I can't post an image of it though because I don't have enough reputation points...

My svg tag looks like so:

```
<div style="height:300px; width:400px; overflow:hidden">
<svg style="position:relative" height="10000" width="10000" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
</div>
```

And I'm adding path elements dynamically using javascript/jquery:

```
var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
$(shape).attr({"d":"...",
               "fill":"none",
               "stroke":color,
               "stroke-width":"1"});
$("svg").append(shape);
```

I left out the value for the path's `d` attribute as it was kind of long.  Also, `color` is a string variable that is determined before hand as either "green", "red", or "black".

Is there something wrong in my code that is causing this or is it a different issue?

Comment: If you can't post a picture, you probably can post a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is probably due to the anti-aliasing applied in most SVG implementations. When the line width goes near or below 1, antialiasing makes it so that half-covered pixels are rendered partially opaque. With the default transforms and viewport in place, your one-pixel line probably sits exactly on the border between two physical pixels, so they're each half covered, leading to an overall 50% transparency. With a black line on a white background, this yields a 50% gray.

Comment: Is there some way I can change that?  When I played around with the svg examples at w3schools.com, lines with stroke-width:1 were showing up just fine without the transparency.

Comment: It depends on the renderer; no idea if there is a way to influence this. There might be a way to turn of anti-aliasing, but there is no standard way that I am aware of.

Comment: Ok I googled this and was able to figure it out.  All I have to do is add shape-rendering:crispEdges to the style of the path element and it shows up as a 1px wide line now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MattL922 You can try to reduce the graphic-size, e.g. instead `height="10000" width="10000"` in the root tag, use something that would fit on a normal screen. Afterwards try to use integers instead of floats for coordinates. That way, the probability of having a line rendered on a full pixel is much higher.

Comment: @feeela Yeah I'm going to start working on that next by scaling and transforming the svg.  Right now I'm plotting the whole price history and shifting the svg left/right based on a slider value - which is why the dimensions are so huge.  Also I converted the prices to cents so I wouldn't get float coords, which def helped.

Answer (score 61):

If the lines are straight horizontal or vertical just place the lines at half a pixel off, like `x="1.5px"`.

Another way is to apply some CSS to the lines:

```
.thelines{
    shape-rendering:crispEdges
}
```

[The spec chapter on shape-rendering property.](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty)

Comment: Thanks, szamil! But actually it's not a cheat because the if the actual line is placed at exact coordinates the stroke is painted on both sides of it, and you actually see two-pixel half transparent line, not a one-pixel opaque.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I was struggling with this from last two hours :P
Reducing stroke width had no effect at all.

Answer (score 22):

maybe a little late, but the real reason for this is that when you draw on a grid-line, which is infinite small, the line with stroke-width 1 is rendered as a half pixel left and right (or above/below) from the grid line. I solved this by adding a group around all objects with transform 0.5,0.5 so everything is shifted a half grid line.

This way everything you draw is now exactly in the middle between 2 grid-lines. A line with stroke width 1 wil have now half a pixel to the left and half a pixel to the right, but both from the middle. Resulting in a line with exactly the thickness you wanted: 1 pixel...

Example:

```
<g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)">
 <g>
   <path />
   <path />
 </g>
 <g>
   <path />
   <path />
 </g>
</g>
```

Comment: This actually fixes any issue, cool!. I just put the transform on the main node, and all the rest looks crisp AND antialiased.

Answer (score 3):

If its D3js then try adding below style attribute to your d3 element:

```
.style('shape-rendering','crispEdges')
```

This makes the line thinner.

If you want to achieve the same with CSS, then add the below style:

```
.the_Line_CLass{
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by user616586 seems fine.

The problem i see is that the lines don't have the same distance from the center of the shape because one of them is offset by 1 px. In most situations thats probably acceptable, but sometimes it isn't.

Another option:

- use a stroke-width of 2px (having 1px rendered outside and 1px rendered inside of the shape)
- apply the shape to itself as a clip-path (removes the rendering of the outer 1px)

Answer (score 0):

fix:

```
<line
  x1="10" y1="1"
  x2="90" y2="1.0001" // hack: horizontal line in SVG not visible in Chrome
  stroke="#FF0000"
  strokeWidth="1"/>
```

Ref: http://code.tonytuan.org/2016/09/svg-horizontal-line-not-visible-in.html